# In CSS, Does IE8-IE9 filter property conflict or may have issue with CSS3 specification filter property?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I asked because I think it's a bit peculiar to write it this way and I may encounter problems:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
filter: grayscale(100%); /* CSS3 */
```

do I need to write it:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50), grayscale(100%);
```

instead?

Comment: You can find very usefull help for grayscale support on http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

Comment: No...they are completely different syntaxes so modern browsers will ignore the earlier versions..and old IE won't recognise the new versions anyway.